# Is there a difference between [object Object] and [domado object HTMLFormElement FORM]?

Tags: javascript, image, forms, object, google-apps-script

My original problem is specific to Apps Script, but I posted an answer that may be helpful in a more generic way.

I've tested HTML and code that works in regular HTML, but doesn't work with the Apps Script HTML Service.  It seems that Apps Script won't accept a FILE object from the browser, but with accept a **FORM** object from the browser.  I can't verify this, but it seems that when a FORM object is sent to the server side `.gs` code with `google.script.run.`, that the code will extract the file from the object correctly, but if I send an INPUT object, it won't extract the file.  I might be wrong, so if anyone can definitively tell me what is going on for the sake of anyone else reading this it would be good.

I'm uploading an image file with a file picker:

```
<form class='frmUpload'>
  <input name="picOneUpload" onchange="picUpload(this.parentNode)" type="file">
</form>
```

As soon as the file is choosen, the `onchange` event runs the JavaScript `picUpload` function in a `<script>` tag.

```
<script>
  window.picUpload = function(frmData) {
    console.log("picUpload ran: " + frmData);

    google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .uploadPic(frmData)
  };
</script>
```

The console.log shows the form data as `[domado object HTMLFormElement FORM]`.
Then the statement `.uploadPic(frmData)` calls a server side `.gs` function, passing the variable `frmData`.  The `.gs` code receives the object into the arg `argBlobInput`:

```
function uploadPic(argBlobInput) { 

  Logger.log('argBlobInput: ' + argBlobInput);
  Logger.log('Keys: ' + Object.keys(argBlobInput));

};
```

The `Logger.log` shows the passed in data as `[object Object]`, not `[domado object HTMLFormElement FORM]`.  If I use `Object.keys(argBlobInput)` I get a return value of the name of the input field: `"picOneUpload"`.  So, `Object.keys()` works in the `.gs` code.  But, if I use `Object.keys(frmData)` in the front end code, no key value gets returned.  I don't understand why `Object.keys()` will work on an object passed to the back end code, but it will NOT work on the object in the front end code?  Maybe something do do with Caja, since this is a Google Apps Script and the HTML is sanitized with Caja?  I don't know?  But if that is true, why will it successfully pass the object to the back end code, and it works there fine?  This makes no sense to me.

How can I get the key values out of the object `[domado object HTMLFormElement FORM]` in the front end?  Even if I explicitly use the input name `picOneUpload`, (which shows up as a key to the object in the back end code) `frmData["picOneUpload"]`, it returns nothing.

What I want to accomplish, is setting the height and width of the image in the front end, before it gets passed to the back end.  But if I can't work with the `[domado object HTMLFormElement FORM]` object, I don't know how I'm going to do that?

If is use JSONstingify on that object:

```
console.log("picUpload data: " + JSON.stringify(frmData));
```

All I get in the console is:  `{}`

I'm guessing that the object is empty except for the image blob.  I guess I'll try putting the file picker in a regular HTML file that doesn't get sanitized by Caja and see what happens.

Okay, I ran the same web page and code without using Google Apps Script, and I get the same issue.  It seems that there is an object, it must have an image file in it, but there are no keys in the object?  I don't understand this.  The image gets passed to the server, then the server uploads a picture to my drive, all without showing that there is anything in the FORM object?

In firefox the object is named:  `[object HTMLFormElement]`

Do I need to access a HTMLFormElement different than a regular object?

Well, I don't think this has anything to do with Apps Script.  I've found another method of retrieving the file from the file picker, which returns a file object:  [object File].

And I can get the name and size of that object.

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('picOneUpload');
var file = fileInput.files[0];

console.log("file: " + file.name + "_file size: " + file.size);
```

Oh, I just figured out how to get the FILE object out of the FORM Object.

```
console.log("picUpload FILE object: " + frmData.files[0]);
```

So, the `[domado object HTMLFormElement FORM]` has yet another object inside of it, the `[object File]` object, but the `[domado object HTMLFormElement FORM]` object has no keys in it I guess?  I might be on my way to solving this problem.

I changed the arg getting passed from `this.parentNode` to just `this`,

```
<input name="picOneUpload" onchange="picUpload(this)">
```

which I prefer because I don't need info from all the elements.  Now, instead of getting the FORM object, I get an INPUT object, which I still need to get the FILE object out of.

So there is:

- [domado object HTMLFormElement FORM] - Google
- [object HTMLFormElement] - Firefox
- [object HTMLInputElement]
- [object File]
- [object Object]

And I'm guessing that there is a label object, since I have a label in the form.  I'm assuming the the FORM object has the most data in it.

Using Firebug, and the DOM tab, files has a list of properties I guess.

- lastModifiedDate
- mozFullPath
- name
- path
- size
- type

So, I guess that is one way to find out what the property names are in the object.

Passing `this` instead of `this.parentNode` doesn't work with Google Apps Script HTML Service.   If I just pass `this` with the input Object, I get an error that the zero property is null, or something like that.  And it looks like the image becomes part of the FileUpload class.

I found this documentation that shows a file upload:
[HTML Service Forms File Upload](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)

Comment: It doesn't really seem to successfully be passing the object, it's passing the string representation of the object, which is `[object, Object]` ?

Comment: The back end code will save the image to my Google Drive, so it's got to be passing the actual data also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.  In the browser, the `this` keyword will create an object filled with information about the element from the reference point of `this`.  And there can be objects inside of objects.  For example, a FILE object inside of an INPUT object, inside of a FORM object.

- [object HTMLFormElement]
- [object HTMLInputElement]
- [object File]

To get the INPUT object out of the FORM object, you can use the `name` attribute in the INPUT tag.

```
//picOneUpload is the name attribute of the FILE input element
console.log("Input Object: " + frmData.picOneUpload);
```

Then to get the FILE object out of the INPUT object, you can uses the `files` property.

```
var file = frmData.picOneUpload.files[0];
console.log("file: " + file);
```

Browsers seem to add a descriptive name to the object to help understand where the object originated from, and what might be in there.

It seems that when there is an object inside of another object, there might not be any key names at all.  So trying to enumerate key names to try to find out how to access the info in that object might not help you.  I just happened to see an example at some website that used the `files` property name to get the file blob out of the FILE object from a file upload picker.  So, I tried it, and I discovered that there was data in an object that I otherwise might have though was empty.

One way to figure out what might be in the object, is to inspect the element that the object came from with something like Firebug, and look for properties in the DOM.  For example, there is `files` and under `files` there is: Size, Type, Name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can get all the property names out of the object.  I had thought that maybe Caja was doing something to prevent the user from getting data out of an object created with `this`.  I just need to loop with a FOR LOOP.

```
  for (var theProperties in frmData) {
    console.log('theProperties: ' + theProperties);
    console.log('loop content: ' + frmData[theProperties]);
  };
```

I should have done this to begin with.  I can get the ELEMENT object out of the FORM object by just using the element property.

```
console.log("elements: " + frmData.elements);
```